# Is it possible to obtain the local IP address from a preprocessor DEFINE in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

This is probably a long shot but doesn't hurt to ask...
Do you think it's possible to obtain the IP address of the build host when building for iOS in Objective-C under xcode?
It'd be useful for my testing if it were possible.
For example:

```
NSString* backendUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:5000/", HOST_IP];
```

Where I would expect `HOST_IP` (if there was something like that) to be something like this, but of course automatically controlled at build time to hold the correct IP:

```
#define HOST_IP @"172.76.77.5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No convenient solution, but here are some options to consider.

1. In your #define, type your computer's Host-Name (if it's on a LAN) - http://mylaptop:5000/
   or simply sign up to a free domain @ http://www.no-ip.com/
2. If it's necessary to specifically have a #define macro that contains your IP Address, you could simply write a small bash script that updates the defined ip in your .m/.cpp/.h file or whatever holds this #define.
   then you can add the script as a pre-build phase, or just run the script when you know that the IP Address has changed. although I admit it's kinda hackish.

Comment: Your no. 2 would be my solution. Bit hacky, but not altogether bad.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but maybe you could do something like

```
static NSString *HOST_IP;

-(id)init
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
       HOST_IP = // Your code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Something like that might work, but I'm not sure what happens when you release the class.

Comment: sorry, this wouldn't work. your method would retain the IP address if the device it's running on. however I was asking for the IP address of the build server (which is also my debug backend server)